# dlopen() is not working with android-n

Tags: android, linux, dlopen, android-7.0-nougat

`dlopen()` is working fine at API-23, but For Android-N, when I tried to open any sofile using `dlopen` it return a `soinfo` structure type pointer. but when i tried to access any variable of this structure the application get crash.

```
si = (soinfo*) dlopen("/data/app/com.xxx.xxx.sampleapp.android-1/lib/x86/libtest.so", RTLD_GLOBAL);

if (si == NULL)
    return;

LOGI("value of dlopen [%d]", si->size);
```

Is there any change in `dlopen()` functionality with Android-N??

Answer (score 8):

`dlopen()` doesn't return a pointer to some `soinfo` structure, it returns `void*`, the standard Linux man page is very specific about this:

> The function dlopen() loads the dynamic shared object (shared library) file named by the null-terminated string filename and returns an opaque "handle" for the loaded object.  This handle is employed with other functions in the dlopen API, such as dlsym(3), dladdr(3), dlinfo(3), and dlclose().

So the fact that you could interpret returned value in some way was non-standard and now Google is just enforcing that with [this change](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/ae74e87%5E!/):

```
commit  ae74e8750b9dae51b24a22fdb4b0e0a2d84f37b9
author  Dimitry Ivanov <dimitry@google.com>
...
linker: hide the pointer to soinfo

Handle no longer is a pointer to soinfo of
a corresponding library. This is done to
prevent access to linker internal fields.

Bug: http://b/25593965
Change-Id: I62bff0d0e5b2dc842e6bf0babb30fcc4c000be24
(cherry picked from commit d88e1f350111b3dfd71c6492321f0503cb5540db)
```

So unless your application is targeting SDK version 23 or less (see `soinfo::to_handle()`), you're now getting the handle that could only be converted back to `soinfo*` with an internal bionic `soinfo_from_handle()`.

Answer (score 2):

From the [developer documentation](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html#ndk) (emphasis added):

> Starting in Android 7.0, the system prevents apps from dynamically linking against non-NDK libraries, which may cause your app to crash. This change in behavior aims to create a consistent app experience across platform updates and different devices.
>   ...
>   All apps generate a runtime error when they call an API that is neither public nor temporarily accessible. **The result is that System.loadLibrary and dlopen(3) both return NULL**, and may cause your app to crash.

Comment: In the question, the asker points out that `dlopen` does not, in fact, return `NULL`. Something else must be happening here, you agree?

Comment: yes. it does not return `NULL`. it return a pointer of unaccessible memory. thats why i am surprised.

Comment: It's not actually a _pointer_, it is a _handle._ Meaning: don't try to access memory through it.

Answer (score 2):

On version of Android that return an opaque handle rather than a pointer to soinfo, the function dl_iterate_phdr() is available. This lets you locate the Elf headers of all the .so's, and the Elf headers contain a great deal of the same information as the soinfo structures.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the change from Google to hide the soinfo to prevent access to linker internal fields.

---

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/d88e1f350111b3dfd71c6492321f0503cb5540db

linker: hide the pointer to soinfo

Handle no longer is a pointer to soinfo of
a corresponding library. This is done to
prevent access to linker internal fields.