# Get the filename of a dynamic library from the pointer returned by dlopen on Android

Tags: android, c

If I only have the opaque handle returned by `dlopen`, which was called somewhere else with the filename used not having trickled down to me, how can I find that filename?
On Linux, I would call `dlinfo`, but it's not available on Android. From within the library itself, I would call `dladdr`, but I do not know any valid address within the library.
I have read about `dl_iterate_phdr` but do not know which of the members of `dl_phdr_info` relates to the handle and thus cannot find the information about the library I am interested in.
Note: according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39325753/dlopen-is-not-working-with-android-n), the opaque handle now really is opaque and casting is not possible anymore.

Comment: As i can understand your question, i think you want to find the filename of a shared obj a pointer that is returned by dlopen am i correct??, soo i think you can use the maps for that the proc/self/maps